# Java M365 Modern Auth OAuth IMAP

Tags: java, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft365

I have a small application that reads incoming Emails via IMAP from an Inbox (Basic Auth). Now Microsoft switched to modern authentication, meaning I have to do this with OAuth. Configuring this in the Email code seems straight forward, but I struggle to configure my M365 Tenant, as I do not have anything like a callback URL or so.
Is there anyone who could help with some documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call back url is nothing but the reply url Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > Search the application by using App ID or Name > open the app and click on authentication blade > update the Redirect URI.

[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That is my problem, I will not have a redirect url, as I do not have an actual user interaction to login. I will have a single small application that uses IMAP to wait for incoming Mails, parse them and forward as a file. Username/Password was configured for this application.

Comment: If your app is single page application then you can add your homepage ( localhost )  URI , hope this helps , thanks .